# Django invite code app recommendation?

Tags: django, registration, django-apps, invite

I'm looking for a simple Django app that restricts registration to users who have an invite code (for running a private beta). I'm using django-registration, so something that plays nicely with it would be great.

Looks like there are several viable options:

[django-inviting](https://github.com/muhuk/django-inviting)
[django-privatebeta](https://github.com/pragmaticbadger/django-privatebeta)
[django-invite](https://bitbucket.org/lorien/django-invite/src)

Given the wealth of options, I'm wondering if people have found a particular app more flexible and/or easier to work with than the others? Are there other apps that I should be aware of?

Comment: If the proverbial wheel's simple enough, sometimes reinventing it is the cheaper option.  I always just roll my own with a salted, hashed random string.  Takes 20 minutes and doesn't have the integration overhead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You miss [django-invitation](https://bitbucket.org/david/django-invitation/overview) which is really quickly integrated with django-registration.
I just had to hack it a bit to include the name of the inviter in the email message.

Answer (score -1):

django-invitation is a good choice among the four.